# Facebook Application - How do i count the number of friends a sender invites?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am doing this facebook invitation (apprequest) but i need to count the number of invitation made by the user, anybody can help me?

The code below works but it only counts 1 invitation no matter how many invites the user sends

```
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId:'<?=$myappid?>',
        cookie:true,
        status:true,
        xfbml:true
    });

    function FacebookInviteFriends()
    {//start of FacebookInviteFriends
        var inviteCounter = FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: '<?=$me['name']?> has invited you to play this game!',
            title: 'Select your friends to play this game!',
            exclude_ids: <?=$allFBStr?>,
            max_recipients: 5
        },
            function (inviteCounter) {

                var userID = '<?=$me['id']?>';
                //alert(userID);
                $.ajax({//ajax
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'addInvitationCounter.php',
                    data: {
                        userID: userID
                    },
                    success: function(result){
                        //alert("SUCCESS: " + result);
                        location.href = "myprofile.php";
                    },
                    error: function(result){
                        alert("ERROR: " + result);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i got your question right, but this is actually against the Facebook policy.

Per section V.1.

> You must not incentivize users to grant additional permissions or use
>   Application Integration Points.

And per the documentation about Application Integration Points

> By "Application Integration Point" we mean Application Info Section,
>   Application tab, Feed, requests (including invites), Publisher, inbox
>   attachments, Chat, Bookmarks, or any other feature of a user profile
>   or Facebook communication channel in which or through which an
>   application can provide, display, or deliver content directed at, on
>   behalf of, or by permission of a user.

Comment: Incentivize users means in real life or in-game? Because for every invites they made in-game, the players will be able to receive 5points

Comment: It explicitly says _“requests (including invites)”_ in what Ronny quoted. And rewarding users for sending invites (inviting others that do not use the app/play the game yet) generates annoying spam – so please don’t do that. Find other ways to promote your game.

Comment: Ronny and CBroe, Thanks for the reply, i will reconsider implementing other features for my project :)

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote an app, where you were getting bonuses depending on how many people you invite, so it is possible. I think you missed to structure of the response object.

When I run the invite code similar to this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'XYZ has invited you to play this game!',
    title: 'Select your friends to play this game!'
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is what `response` looks like *(IDs are changed, see the XYZ)*

```
{
  request: "634814526537XYZ",
  to: [
    0: "100000526972XYZ"
    1: "100000756092XYZ"
  ]
}
```

So there's always two entries in the resonse object, one of them is 'to', an array with the invited ids. The number of invited people is accessed like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'XYZ has invited you to play this game!',
    title: 'Select your friends to play this game!'
}, function (response) {
    var numberOfInvites = response.to.length;
    alert('You have invited '+ numberOfInvites +'People');
});
```

But I don't know of any policies permitting this, so that's a topic you should read about.